# Solving an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given the  dimensionless Hubble function:

$$E^2(z)  = \biggl ( \frac{H(z)}{H_0} \biggr)^2 = \Omega_m(1+z)^3+ (1-\Omega_m)e^{\int_0^z\frac{1+w0+w1*z}{1+z} dz} $$

I would like to calculate  the luminosity distance
$$d_l= \frac{(1+z)}{H_0}\int_0^z \frac{H_0}{H(z)}dz$$

as function of $\Omega_m, w_0,w_1,z$. For those interested in the meaning of these parameters, the first the matter component of the Universe, the second and the third one are parameters used to describe dark energy and the last one is the redshift which is a positive number.

The integral at the exponential is easy to solve with `Assumptions`

```
fun1[y] = 
 E^Integrate[(1 + w0 + w1*z)/(1 + z), {z, 0, y}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    z > 0 && z \[Epsilon] Reals && y > 0 && y \[Epsilon] Reals]
```

and gives

> w1 y + (1 + w0 - w1) Log[1 + y]

but the second one is giving me some trouble since Mathematica only gives the symbolic output. I tried with

`e[y_] := Sqrt[ omegam *(1 + z)^3 + (1 - omegam)*E^fun1[y]]`

`Integrate[1/e[z], {z, 0, y},  Assumptions ->  z > 0 && z \[Epsilon] Reals && y > 0 && y \[Epsilon] Reals]`

but honestly I am not sure anymore since it has been a while since I used Mathematica consistently. I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What 's known about the parameters `w0,w1,omegam` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann ah yes i forgot to write that H_0 is 73 km/(s*parsec)

Answer (score 3):

Try with additional assumptions `w0,w1,omegam`

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[omegam*(1 + z)^3 + (1 - omegam)*E^fun1[z]] , {z, 0, y}, 
Assumptions ->omegam > 0 && w0 == -1 && w1 == 0 && z > 0 && z \[Epsilon] Reals &&y > 0 && y \[Epsilon] Reals]
```

[image]

Integrate gives the result depending on some extra conditions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: in the previous comment i explained poorly the issue.  we don't really know if the lcdm model is correct so i cannot really place those conditions on w0 and w1. all we know is that since the lcdm explain a lot of things the real values should be closer to it. i can add the assumption on omega_m tho.

Comment: In your ?deleted? comment you recommended `w1==0&&w0==-1`, that's what i tried in my answer

Comment: i know  i know, but after you posted your answer i thought about it and realized i was wrong.